# Define Custom Big Objects: No package.xml found

Tags: deployment, workbench, big-object

I am working on the

> Developer Intermediate Big Object Basics Define Custom Big Objects

I am not able to finish the challenge because I can not upload the zip file successfully through workbench. I select the options for:

> Check Only && Single Package

[image]
This is the structure of my zip file

Here are the xml files:
rider_history__b.object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <deploymentStatus>Deployed</deploymentStatus>

    <fields>
        <fullName>Start_Location_Lat__c</fullName>
        <label>Start Location Latitude</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>Number</type>
        <precision>7</precision>
        <scale>4</scale>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>

    <fields>
        <fullName>Start_Location_Long__c</fullName>
        <label>Start Location Longitude</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>Number</type>
        <precision>7</precision>
        <scale>4</scale>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>

    <fields>
        <fullName>Start_Time__c</fullName>
        <label>Start time</label>
        <required>true</required>
        <type>DateTime</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>

    <fields>
        <fullName>End_Time__c</fullName>
        <label>End time</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>DateTime</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>

    <fields>
        <fullName>Service_Type__c</fullName>
        <label>Service Type</label>
        <length>16</length>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>

    <fields>
        <fullName>Rider_Account__c</fullName>
        <label>Rider Account</label>
        <length>16</length>
        <required>true</required>
        <type>Text</type>
    </fields>

    <fields>
        <fullName>Rider_Rating__c</fullName>
        <label>Rider Rating</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>Number</type>
        <precision>2</precision>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>

    <indexes>
        <fullName>Rider_History_Index</fullName>
        <label>Rider History Index</label>
        <fields>
            <name>Rider_Account__c</name>
            <sortDirection>DESC</sortDirection>
        </fields>
        <fields>
            <name>Start_Time__c</name>
            <sortDirection>DESC</sortDirection>
        </fields>
    </indexes>

    <label>Rider History</label>
    <pluralLabel>Rider Histories</pluralLabel>
</CustomObject>
```

rider_history.permissionset

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <label>Rider History Permission Set</label>

    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Rider_History__b.Start_Location_Lat__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>

    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Rider_History__b.Start_Location_Long__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>

    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Rider_History__b.Service_Type__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>

    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Rider_History__b.Rider_Rating__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>

    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Rider_History__b.End_Time__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>

</PermissionSet>
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">  
   <types>  
     <members>*</members>  
     <name>CustomObject</name>  
   </types>  
   <types>  
     <members>*</members>  
     <name>PermissionSet</name>  
   </types>  
   <version>41.0</version>  
</Package>
```

If you have any ideas it would be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Can you check your zip folder for any hidden files that may have been created during the file compression stage?

Comment: Hi TSmith, there are no hidden files.

Comment: Try unchecking the checkOnly flag.

Comment: No this does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The archive of the folder was breaking the logic somehow. There were not hidden folders however. When I tried with different archive it worked.